# How can I add sequelize or condition between first third level table table?

Tags: sql, node.js, orm, sequelize.js

The scenario is like

> tabel1 => fiestname, lastname, email,

> table2 => other fields (child table of table1)

> table3 => name, description (child table of table1)

query is like:

```
table1.findAndCountAll({
    include:[
        {
            where: {
                // need a OR like condition between table1's  fiestname, lastname, email and table3's name 
            }
            model: table2,
            include:[
                {
                    model: table3,
                    as: `table3`
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
})
```

I already try with $ like:

```
[Op.or]: [
    { email: { [Op.like]: "%" + search + "%" } },
    { firstname: { [Op.like]: "%" + search + "%" } },
    { lastname: { [Op.like]: "%" + search + "%" } },
    { '$table3.name$': { [Op.like]: "%" + search + "%" } },
]
```

but it's working with second level (table2 not for third level)

And associations relations between tables are:

```
table1.hasMany(models.table2, { foreignKey: 'table1_id' });
table3.hasMany(models.table3, { foreignKey: 'table2_id', as: "table2" });
```

Comment: Show how did you try with `$` for the third level

Comment: @Anatoly added in question.

Comment: Now can you add generated SQL query for `{ '$table3.name$': { [Op.like]: "%" + search + "%" } },`?

Comment: @Anatoly it's execute one sub query on table1 and apply this condition in sub query so it's return error like column table3.name not found.

Comment: And what alias is for `table3` there in SQL?

Comment: @Anatoly mention in code it's table3

Comment: Please add association definitions between all three models

Comment: @Anatoly added in question

Comment: The second association looks a bit weird. Please correct it

Comment: And if you execute `findAll` instead of `findAndCountAll` - how many SQL requests will be executed?

Comment: @Anatoly can you please guide me which kind of changes required in second axxociation, and I need count as well that's why I am using `findAndCountAll`

Comment: You indicated that `table3` associated with itself but using `table2_id` and with the alias `table2` as if this association should be like this `table2.hasMany(models.table3, { foreignKey: 'table2_id', as: "table3" });`

Comment: I proposed to execute `findAll` just for testing purposes to find out how many SQL queries would be executed

Comment: @Anatoly do your suggestions but not working :(

Comment: Wait, please confirm that both tables table2 and table3 are child tables for table1